# window.open not working in chrome 6

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to open a location in new window(tab) using window.open. It is not working in chrome. First I tried with window.open(url,name), this did not work, however this works in every other browser. Then I used something like this,

```
var w = window.open("about:blank");
w.opener = null;
w.document.location = url;
```

This opens the url in same tab but not in separate tab.

Comment: The tiny popup blocker icon skipped my eye. Thanks guys...:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure your popup is not being blocked? Most popup windows that didn't happen in response to a user event will get blocked. I typed window.open("google.com", "_blank") into the console and I got the blocked window on the url bar

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
window.open( url, "_blank" );
```

Remember, the 2nd parameter is analogous to an anchor tag's `target` attribute.

Comment: Peter, this is not working :(. I am not using anchor tag, its a flash, when clicked, the url has to open in new tab.

Comment: Chrome is probably blocking it, then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Works in IE8, fails in FF when popups are blocked

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof HTMLElement!='undefined'&&!HTMLElement.prototype.click)
HTMLElement.prototype.click=function(){ // event by Jason Karl Davis
var evt = this.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, this.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
function loadAndClick(url,target) {
  var lnk = document.createElement("a");
  lnk.href=url;
  lnk.target=target||"_blank"
  lnk.id="myLink"
  lnk.onclick=function() {
    var w = window.open(this.href,this.target);
    return (w)?false:true;
  }
  document.body.appendChild(lnk);
  document.getElementById('myLink').click();
//  lnk.click();
}
window.onload=function() { // or call getURL("javascript:loadAndClick('http://www.google.com')");
  loadAndClick("http://www.google.com");
}  
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a redirect page (for example Redirect.aspx).

```js
window.open('Redirect.aspx?URL=http://www.google.com', '_blank');
```

From the Redirect.aspx page, redirect to the URL specified in the QS...

This worked a treat for me with Chrome blocking my new windows.

Comment: I'm not getting local files to be ignored by the popup blocker, i.e. opening a file at /some-file.php still triggers Chrome's popup blocker. Chrome v.20.